# Self join a table showing parent child relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `sales`. In it there are columns `catid`, `desc`, `parentforeignkey` and the records are something like this:

```
catid       desc        parentforeignkey 


   1,       clothes,         1
   2,       shoes,           1 
   3,       socks,           1
   4,       gloves,          1
   5,       mittens,         4
   6,       leather gloves,  4 
   7,       plain gloves,    4


...
```

How do I build a query to show this relationship?

Comment: which is parent foreign column here? what is your expected output

Comment: This suggests that the parent of 'clothes' is 'clothes' and the parent of 'gloves' is 'shoes'. Is that right?

Comment: gloves are a child of shoes?

Comment: its dummy data but yea its something like this so the first column is primary key second is description third is foreign key

Comment: so what is expected output? can you print out please

Comment: result should be table with repeating parents showing children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ma take a shot at this, but I'm struggling to see the question. I feel like you want a query that groups the selection by the parent foreignkey and then lists the catid and desc for each parent. So basically something like

```
SELECT t.parentforeignkey, t.catid, t.desc
FROM table1 as t
GROUP BY t.parentforeignkey, t.catid, t.desc;
```

NOTE: be careful with "desc" as a column name as DESC is a reserved word for descending (used for sorting)

That will give you a result like:

`ParentForeignKey      | CatID      | Desc
          1                 1          Clothes
          1                 2          Shoes
          2                 2          Shoes
          3                 1          Clothes`

So the trick is to use GROUP BY to assign the parent and child groups. Be careful though, because the order of the group by command matters (`GROUP BY Catid, ParentforeignKey` yields a different result than what I listed above). Also, you need to explicitely say how each column is related to the grouping. If you leave a column out, you'll likely get an error (depending on your DBMS) that says something like "You tried to specify a query that does not include the specified expression as part of the aggregate function"

EDIT: I now see that you've included the DBMS in your question. If you're using the BIDS or SSRS then this is supremely easy, you'll what a query that just selects the data (and filters whatever you want out) and then you'll go to the tablix controls and define the parent group to the details as catid, and the parent of catid as foreignparentkey and then the table should take care of itself!

Comment: catid is a primary key that can not be repeated in a table but foreign key can be but it comes from same table

Comment: if catid is a primary key then it is unique for every observation, in which case the point is moot - you don't want a grouping, you just want an ordering. So just `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ParentForiegnKey` <- that will list the parent foreign key in order, and then the primary cat id will be out of order.